Custom sort list in Python
There are a number of files in a folder like this:
'920.jpg'
'920-1.jpg'
'920-2.jpg'

When I want to get a list of files, the order of the files is as follows:
[
    '920-1.jpg',
    '920-2.jpg',
    '920.jpg'
]

How can I get a list where the order of the files is exactly the same as the order of the files in Windows folder?
I used os.listdir() and glob module, but did not succeed.

The term you need to search for is "natural sort".

I used  natsorted(glob.glob(r'\*.jpg')) did not succeed.

I guess there's more to it than natural sorting, you also need to split the base filename and extension.

You can use natsorted, but you have to split each filename from its extension first.  The . in the extension can't be part of the comparison.
import natsort
import os
files=[
    '920-1.jpg',
    '920-2.jpg',
    '920.jpg'
]
files_split = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f)) for f in files]
files_split
[('920-1', '.jpg'), ('920-2', '.jpg'), ('920', '.jpg')]
[''.join(f) for f in natsort.natsorted(files_split)]
['920.jpg', '920-1.jpg', '920-2.jpg']


import os

folder_path = "/path/to/your/folder"
files = os.listdir(folder_path)

sorted_files = sorted(files, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0].split('-')[-1]))

print(sorted_files)


This answer is very specific to the example used, it doesn't generalize very well.
